# iTextSharp Checkboxes disappear in PDF when saving

Tags: c#, pdf, checkbox, itext, acrobat

I'm using iTextSharp to fill my form fields on my template with values.
Some of this fields should be flattened so that the user can't edit it.
The rest of the fields should be filled by the user and my program can read out the data and insert it into the database.

My Solution works fine with Abobe Reader DC, but I have problems with Adobe Reader X. An update of the version on the clients isn't possible.

So I enabled usage rights in the PDF template. The problem is that with iTextSharp I have to enable append on the PdfStamper. If this is enabled, it's not possible to flatten a part of the form because of the Adobe signature on the document.

Now I have following idea:

I split my template into two documents. The first document is filled using my code and Formflattening is true.

Here's the Code:

```
MemoryStream outstream = new MemoryStream();

Document document = new Document();
PdfSmartCopy writer = new PdfSmartCopy(document, outstream);
document.Open();

//newFileStream is the flattend Form
pdfReader = new PdfReader(newFileStream.ToArray());
writer.AddDocument(pdfReader);

PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(Properties.Resources.PdfForm);
writer.AddDocument(reader);

reader.Close();
writer.Close();
document.Close();

return outstream.ToArray();
```

Now I merge the document with my second template and save it then I have the document that I want. The first page is 'readonly' and the second page has formfields.

My problem is now that the user can fill the document (checkboxes and textboxes) but if the user saves the document the filled checkboxes disappear. Hence, if the user sends me back the document there are no checkboxes in it.

I don't understand why only checkboxes disappear.

Comment: Do I correctly understand that you say you split and later merge again parts of a Reader-enabled PDF? In that case the issue most likely simply is that the final, merged PDF is not Reader-enabled anymore and old Adobe Reader versions won't save form-fill-ins anymore. It this is not the case, please share a PDF in all the stages of processing up to the stage in which saving the document loses the checkboxes.